# What's causing my windows 10 firewall to block Docker drive sharing?

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I have been following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) on Docker's documentation to try to learn how to develop Django websites using Docker. When I try running the

```
sudo docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .
```

command, I get an error that states the following:

```
Cannot create container for service web: b'Drive sharing seems blocked by a firewall'
```

I tried going into Docker's settings and setting the C drive to be accessible to containers, but then I get an error that says:

```
Firewall detected
A firewall is blocking file sharing between Windows and the containers. See documentation for more info.
```

I've tried googling around for some different solutions. I've tried going through [this github thread](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/355), and I've tried, for example, changing the vEthernet(DockerNAT) properties. I've also tried some other troubleshooting methods, which I will link below:

[Link 1](https://success.docker.com/article/error-a-firewall-is-blocking-file-sharing-between-windows-and-the-containers)

[Link 2](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2677#issuecomment-517427501)

[Link 3](https://windowsreport.com/error-response-daemon-drive-sharing-blocked-firewall/)

So far, nothing I has tried worked. I am trying to do this on a work computer that runs Windows 10 Enterprise, however I have talked with my IT team and I have been told that the firewall is not blocking any ports or programs that would keep Docker from running. Is it possible that I am missing something? Any kind of insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried disabling WSL? Go to Docker tray icon -> Settings -> General -> Disable WSL and you'll see in Resources a FILE SHARING menu. Now, windows is not managing permissions, when dockers are in Hyper-V mode